# Paypal TLS Security changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, paypal

As you all probably know, Paypal is upgrading TLS security protocols to 1.2. .Net 3.5 does NOT support this - I have a website in .Net 3.5 Framework which makes use of Paypal payments. What are my alternatives?

Updating will require huge changes to my solution and it is not ideal, not enough resources and time -

Comment: Update to the last .Net Framework

Comment: Updating will require huge changes to my solution and it is not ideal, not enough resources and time - what are my alternatives?

Comment: You should contact to Paypal, sure they will help you.

Comment: A quick and temp fix is to install Fiddler to decrypt traffic and reencrpt using TLS 1.2, but it's probably time for you to explore upgrading to .NET 4.5+

Comment: Thanks for the fiddler tip - will look into it. I contacted Paypal, they were not helpful at all and simply reported back that they are upgrading and I must make all changes required.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution for not only a C# project stuck on 3.5 but also for any system that is not able to directly implement TLS 1.2 is to use a relay or proxy that does support that.

This obviously adds some complexity because you need to slot a service in between yours and the destination but if you need to upgrade then that could be a stepping stone to the upgrade.

This is essentially the same solution suggested by Raskayu for using Fiddler but expanded to use any language to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You can set this static property

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.90).aspx